# Prove that $(A\cap C)-B=(C-B)\cap A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Prove that $(A\cap C)-B=(C-B)\cap A$

$\mathbf{My\ attempt:}$

Looking at LHS, assuming $(A\cap C)-B \neq \emptyset$

Let $x\in (A\cap C)-B$

This implies $x\in A$ and $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$

Looking at RHS, assuming $(C-B)\cap A \neq \emptyset$,

Let $y \in (C-B)\cap A$

This implies $y\in C$ and $y\notin B$ and $y\in A$

By comapring the LHS and RHS, we find that:
$$
x,y\in A
$$

$$
x,y\in C
$$

$$
x,y\notin B
$$

Thus LHS = RHS.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think you made a small error in the first step of the LHS: you say $x\in A$ and $x\in C$ and $x\notin C$, which is a contradiction. I think you meant $x\notin B$.

Comment: Ah yes, fixed the error. Thanks.

Comment: in the fifth line it should be $x\notin B$ not $C$

Comment: and yes it's correct

Comment: You should convince yourself that you can prove this without writing a word down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the typo, yes.  In short.

$$\begin{align}&(A\cap C)\smallsetminus C \\ =~&\{x:(x\in A\wedge x\in C)\wedge x\notin B\}\\=~&\{x:(x\in C\wedge x\notin B)\wedge x\in A\}\\=~&(C\smallsetminus B)\cap A\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
(A\cap C) - B = (A\cap C)\cap\overline{B} = (C\cap\overline{B})\cap A = (C - B)\cap A
\end{align*}